# Rails - added new mime type (AMP), now all my JS requests have turned into AMP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, amp-html

I'm implementing [Google AMP pages](https://www.ampproject.org/) for a subset of my Rails 3 site.

In order to support `.amp.html` templates, I added a new mime type to `/config/initializers/mime_types.rb`:

`Mime::Type.register 'text/html', :amp`

However, strange thing has happened. When I look in the console, it's processing all js requests as AMP! If I hit a normal html page, everything looks right:

`Processing by ExampleController#index as HTML`

But all javascript requests have turned into:

`Processing by ExampleController#index as AMP`

The requests are strangely working, but this doesn't seem right. Why did this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved. Looks like I needed to do

`Mime::Type.register_alias 'text/html', :amp`

`register_alias` instead of `register`